# Alternate CD image downloaded last year gives different hash

Tags: iso, md5sum

I had downloaded the alternate CD images through torrents some time last year, and now that I need it again I decided to check it's md5 hash.

```
$ md5sum ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso 
b502888194367acdec4d79203e7a539c  ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso
```

Now the problem is, the reference hashes it's supposed to match to is completely different:

```
24da873c870d6a3dbfc17390dda52eb8  ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso
```

Can I safely conclude the image I downloaded is corrupted?

**Reference**

- [UbuntuHashes - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if the md5sum does not match, then the file is corrupt.  You can restart the torrent and it should correct any errors by downloading the damaged parts again.

Answer (score 0):

Try in Live Mode writing the image to a USB via UNetbootin. You will save a disc in case the image is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently repaired my corrupted "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso" file, which I downloaded with free Internet Download Manager (IDM). The md5sum of this file was not matching with the correct one and when I tried to boot using a live usb it said something like "corrupted kernel image". I did some googling and finally repaired the file using torrent as follows:-

I never used torrent before so I first downloaded a torrent client (uTorrent) and got a bit familiar to it. Then i found a torrent file of the exact iso. Afterwards I
put the corrupted iso image in the location* where the file was about to be downloaded by torrent, BEFORE STARTING THE TORRENT DOWNLOAD for the file. And when I started the torrent download then instead of starting the file download it checked the corrupted file kept at the location by me and downloaded 10 or 15 MB of corrupted data and when I checked the md5sum with Cygwin it matched with the correct one. I was saved from re-downloading the 701 MB file on my costly 3G data pack.

**P.S:** this location can be easily known by starting the client from the torrent file and looking at the location it prompts to save the file